# onsubmit function does not invoke correctly using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I want to make some validations when the form submitted. However when the form submitted validation function seems like invoking correctly. The alert part doesn't come up but when i try to alert like this

```
function validation(){
      alert("somethinglol");
      var username = $("#register.username").val().toString();
     
       
       
       alert(username);
     };
```

somethinglol appears but the second alert doesn't.

This is my get function:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs');
})
```

This is the index.ejs

```
<form id="form1" action="/" method="post" onSubmit="validation();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="register.username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="register.username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpRegisterUsername" class="text-muted">You should enter a username.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="register.password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="register.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Enter a password.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="register.confirm.password">Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmedPassword" id="register.confirm.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Confirm password</small>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="registerSubmit" value="Submit"></input>

    </form>
```

This is the script part of index.js which contains the validation() function.

```
<script>
     function validation(){
      alert($("#register.username").val().toString());
      var username = $("#register.username").val().toString();
      username = "somethinglol";
       
       
       alert(username);
     };
</script>
```

I have changed the script as external but it didn't work. I have changed the jquery cdn. I used `$("#registerSubmit").click(...)` instead of onSubmit but it didn't work again. I also tried something using async and await but if it's the problem I am not sure that I did it correctly.

Comment: remove the ending tag of <input>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jquery you can use `$( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {` to perform an action before the submit

moreover to select id with dot (.) in jquery you have to use \\ before dot

```
$("#register\\.username")
```

```js
$( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert($("#register\\.username").val().toString());
      var username = $("#register\\.username").val().toString();
      username = "somethinglol";
      alert(username);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="/" method="post" onSubmit="validation();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="register.username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="register.username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpRegisterUsername" class="text-muted">You should enter a username.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="register.password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="register.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Enter a password.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="register.confirm.password">Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmedPassword" id="register.confirm.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Confirm password</small>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="registerSubmit" value="Submit"></input>

    </form>
```